# How to print/export a class's list of members in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, visual-studio-2015, coderush

How to print/export a class's list of members in Visual Studio 2015? I have one class with a lot of methods. The class diagram's fit option makes the font too small. Resharper's 9.2 File Structure export option doesn't work at all for me. (I have access to CodeRush but I don't know if it has this functionality.)

Comment: Walk it with reflection, generate a PDF ? Look for Roslyn based tools? Where is the image going to go, printer? powerpoint?

Comment: Going to the printer to fit the paper.